# CSS Expandable Text in Table Cell is Showing Checkbox

Tags: css, text, html-table, hidden, expand

I employed the CSS trick to hide a checkbox on expandable text in a CSS table cell, however, the checkbox is showing when it is supposed to be hidden (see pic).  The "view source" code from FireFox is listed below exactly as it was written to the file.  Any suggestions for getting rid of the checkbox?  The text does also not expand, so I think something is off?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<style type="text/css">
 table.gridtable {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color: black;
    border-width:  2px;
    border-color: Black
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid;
}
 table.gridtable th {
    color: Black;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #EEEEFF;
}
 table.gridtable tr {
    color: Black;
}
 table.gridtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
}
 table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: White
}
 table.gridtable td {
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-Color: #8080FF;
}
 .content{
  height:  15px;
  width:100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
Input()[type='checkbox'] { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; }
Input()[type='checkbox']:checked + .content { height: auto; width: auto;}
</style>
<table class="gridtable" Align=center>
<tr><th>Group</th><th>Indication</th></tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">approved</td><td><label><input type ="checkbox" /><div class="content"><span class="hidden">
Indicated for the maintenance of ....
</span></div></label></td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have `Input()[type='checkbox']` which should be changed to 
`input[type='checkbox']`. So if you remove the `()` and it should work.

Also I noticed that your text is being cut off in one of the table cells and you might want to remove the `height: 15px` on the `.content` class so all the text shows.

Also also just an observation but you have a `div` inside a `label` tag and to my knowledge that is not good HTML structure and I suggest removing the `label` since it doesn't seem like its being used. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - working on it now. Online examples don't have a semicolon ";" after the ellipses, so is that correct, or a semicolon needed?

Comment: In CSS you don't need a semicolon after the last entry in a group of properties. Me personally I always add one to the last entry to avoid running into errors if I add an additional entry below the last one.

Answer (score 0):

## CSS Solution

---

### Ellipsis…

---

When you use ellipsis on content of a table, you need to setup your elements with the following:

- 2 containers inside `<td>` one on the outside (`.content`) then the other one (`.hidden`) will be inside the outer container. Text will be in `.hidden`.
- The outer container needs the following (`label.content`):

  ```
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  ```
- The inner container needs the following (`b.hidden`):

  ```
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  ```

---

### Labels and Checkboxes

---

The best way to hide a checkbox is to place it higher in the DOM than it's intended target so cascading provides control and then use `display:none`. With `display:none` the checkbox doesn't get in the way of other elements. Elements that are `visibility` or `opacity` still exist in the normal document flow.

With checkbox out of the way but not really clickable (user can't see it), use a `<label for='checkboxID'>`. The attribute [for] with the value of checkbox's #id allows the `<label>` to be the checkbox (clicking it will also click the checkbox)

---

### Slide IN/OUT

---

The established behavior is:

- `label.content` is clicked
- `input[type=checkbox]#chx` is now checked
- `b.hidden` 2nd state is triggered
- `label.content` is clicked again
- `input[type=checkbox]#chx` is now unchecked
- `b.hidden` reverts back to 1st state

`b.hidden` 1st state is as follows:

```
 max-height: 50px;
 max-width: 200px;
 transition: .7s ease-out;
```

`b.hidden` 2nd state is as follows:

```
 max-height: 500px;
 max-width: 1800px;
 transition: .7s ease;
 white-space: normal;
 overflow: visible;
```

---

### Demo

---

```css
table.gridtable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: Black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 75%;
}

table.gridtable th {
  color: Black;
  border-width: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
}

table.gridtable tr {
  color: Black;
}

table.gridtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
}

table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: White
}

table.gridtable td {
  border-width: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-Color: #8080FF;
  width: 50%;
}

label.content {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#chx {
  display: none
}

b.hidden {
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: .7s ease-out;
}

#chx:checked+.content .hidden {
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 1800px;
  transition: .7s ease;
  /* Remove white-space if you want the animation go horizontal */
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <style>

  </style>

  <table class="gridtable">
    <tr>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Indication</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>approved</td>
      <td>
        <input id='chx' type="checkbox" />
        <label for='chx' class="content">
      <b class="hidden">
   LOOOONNGGG WOOOORRRRDDSS TTOOOO TESSSSSSSST EEEEEELLLIIPSISSSS AAANNDDD WWWWARRPPPIIINNGGGG
</b>
</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I like the animated effect.   However, the long text appears bold, and isn't that because the <b>text</b> is the bold tag?  How can the normal font be used?

Comment: Replace `<b>` with just about any tag you want. Well within reason of course an `<iframe>` has too many special behaviors but a more generic tag like `<span>` is a good substitute. I just used `<b>` because I tend to be terse and minimal when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

@Crazymatt, below is the solution that worked.  I removed the () per your suggestion but had to leave the label tag, since it wouldn't work without a label tag. (see this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/4h75G/13/) where I fetched the example CSS code, which uses a label tag.)  Also, I needed the height and made it 30px.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<style type="text/css">
 table.gridtable {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color: black;
    border-width:  2px;
    border-color: Black
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid;
}
 table.gridtable th {
    color: Black;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #EEEEFF;
}
 table.gridtable tr {
    color: Black;
}
 table.gridtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
}
 table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: White
}
 table.gridtable td {
 max-width:  100px;
 overflow: hidden;
 Text-overflow: ellipsis
 white-Space() nowrap;
    border-width:   0px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-Color: #8080FF;
}
 .content{
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  Text-overflow: ellipsis
}
Input[type='checkbox'] { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; }
Input[type='checkbox']:checked + .content { height: auto; width: auto;}
</style>
<table class="gridtable" Align=center>
<tr><th>Group</th><th>Indication</th></tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">approved</td><td><label><input type ="checkbox" /><div class="content"><span class="hidden">
Indicated for the maintenance ... very long text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
</span></div></label></td>
</tr> 
</table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@zerOOne, I actually have multiple cells which require hidden overlap, and with multiple cells in the example below, only the first cell can expand/contract:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<style type="text/css">
table.gridtable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: Black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: solid;
}

table.gridtable th {
  color: Black;
  border-width: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
}

table.gridtable tr {
  color: Black;
}

table.gridtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
}

table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: White
}

table.gridtable td {
  border-width: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-Color: #8080FF;
}

label.content {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#chx {
  display: none
}

.hidden {
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: .7s ease-out;
}

#chx:checked+.content .hidden {
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 1800px;
  transition: .7s ease;
  /* Remove white-space if you want the animation go horizontal */
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: visible;
}
</style>


  <table class="gridtable">
    <tr>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Indication</th>
      <th>Indication</th>
      <th>Indication</th>
      <th>Indication</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>approved</td>
      <td>
        <input id='chx' type="checkbox" />
        <label for='chx' class="content">
      <div class="hidden">
   LOOOONNGGG WOOOORRRRDDSS TTOOOO TESSSSSSSST EEEEEELLLIIPSISSSS AAANNDDD WWWWARRPPPIIINNGGGG
</div>
</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id='chx' type="checkbox" />
        <label for='chx' class="content">
      <div class="hidden">
   LOOOONNGGG WOOOORRRRDDSS TTOOOO TESSSSSSSST EEEEEELLLIIPSISSSS AAANNDDD WWWWARRPPPIIINNGGGG
</div>
</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id='chx' type="checkbox" />
        <label for='chx' class="content">
      <div class="hidden">
   LOOOONNGGG WOOOORRRRDDSS TTOOOO TESSSSSSSST EEEEEELLLIIPSISSSS AAANNDDD WWWWARRPPPIIINNGGGG
</div>
</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id='chx' type="checkbox" />
        <label for='chx' class="content">
      <div class="hidden">
   LOOOONNGGG WOOOORRRRDDSS TTOOOO TESSSSSSSST EEEEEELLLIIPSISSSS AAANNDDD WWWWARRPPPIIINNGGGG
</div>
</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```